# how to display an error message if email and password is not valid in firebase swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Try to develop login page in swift then I want to validate certain condition for error return.

from print(Error.localizeDescription) I get some return like

- The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
- There is no user record corresponding to this identifier.

How to validate that condition based on Error.localizeDescription ?

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: {[weak self] result, Error in
            guard let StrongSelf = self else{
                return
            }
            
            if let Error = Error {
                print(Error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            guard Error == nil else{
                // in here there is validation of return error (e.g. wrong password, account not exist)
                self?.reasonLabel.isHidden=false
                self?.reasonLabel.text=Error
                return
            }
            
            self!.checkinfo()
            
            
        })
```

Comment: Hey lauwis. Any update here? 

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not to declare any property capitalized, instead use lowercased or camel if need so.
second if you using [weak self] and make guard let condition then use strong one to prevent retain cycle and try to do not use force unwrap.

```
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: {[weak self] result, error in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            let alert = UIAlertController.configureAlertController(error.localizedDescription)
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
            return
        }
        // your logic

       /* or 
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            UIAlertController. showAlert(error.localizedDescription)
        }else{
         // your logic
        }
       */

       /* or
       
       guard let result = result else {
       UIAlertController. showAlert(error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error")
       return
       }

       // your logic
       */

       /* 
        or some else, but avoid force unwrap
       */
    })
```

Notice that your `if let` statement with error check won't prevent execution of your whole code and `self!.checkinfo()` will be performed, `return` in the end of `if let error..` will tell your method that he needs to stop

```
 extension UIAlertController {
     static func configureAlertController(with title: String = "Attention", message: String) -> (UIAlertController){
         let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
         let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ОК",  style: .default) {(action) in}
         alertController.addAction(action)
    
         return alertController
     }
 }
```

Comment: is there any reason why there is a popup about UIAlertController has no member configureAlertController

Comment: not sure what do you mean, make an extension for UIAlertController and create your custom method and call it configureAlertController - it would be ur member. If you don't need UIAlertController, but need to `self.reasonLabel.isHidden = false` `self.reasonLabel.text = error.localizedDescription` make it instead of alert

Comment: @lauwispremium any way this part of your code don't trigger compile error? `self?.reasonLabel.text=Error` it should be kinda `self?.reasonLabel.text=Error.localizedDescription` - it's a `String`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a specific action based on the error that Firebase Authentication raises, parsing the `Error.localizeDescription` is not the best way to do that. Instead check the error `code` of the `NSError` object you get in the completion handler again the values shown in the documentation on [handling errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors).

For example (based on this [repo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/70e424c8b3740597d17ad7f25c5f98918a567bc0/functions/FunctionsExampleSwift/SignInViewController.swift#L44-L56):

```
switch error {
  case let .some(error as NSError)
    where UInt(error.code) == FUIAuthErrorCode.userCancelledSignIn.rawValue:
    print("User cancelled sign-in")
  case .none:
    if let user = authDataResult?.user {
      signed(in: user)
    }
  }
}
```